# $(g(X_t))_{t \geq 0}$ is continuous in probability if $g$ is uniformly continuous and $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ continuous in probability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

How to prove this fact?

$(X_{t})_{t \ge 0}$ is continuous stochastic process(It means that $\lim_{s \to t}P(\left|X_{t}-X_{s} \right|>\epsilon)=0)$) and function $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous. Show that $g(X_{t})_{t \ge 0}$ is continuous stochastic process.

It is what I have solves so far:

$\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta >0 $ $|X_{t}-X{s}|<\delta$ so $|g(X_{t})-g(X{s})|<\epsilon$

Lets take it under probability(Can I say:)

$\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta >0 $ $P(|X_{t}-X{s}|<\delta)$ so $P(|g(X_{t})-g(X{s})|<\epsilon)$

It dosent make much sense but I feel that I need to use this fact: $P(X<\epsilon)=1-P(x>\epsilon)$

I just dont know how to use that $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous. Not sure how to write this...

Comment: Also, what have you tried?  Please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960/822

Comment: I tried. I edited post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon>0$. By the uniform continuity of $g$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that

$$|x-y| \leq \delta \implies |g(x)-g(y)| \leq \epsilon.$$

This implies

$$\{\omega; |g(X_t(\omega))-g(X_s(\omega))| > \epsilon\} \subseteq \{\omega; |X_t(\omega)-X_s(\omega)| >\delta\}.$$

Hence,

$$\mathbb{P}(|g(X_t)-g(X_s)| > \epsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}(|X_t-X_s| > \delta) \xrightarrow[]{s \to t} 0$$

where we have used in the last step the continuity of $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$.

Comment: Can you explain this $\{\omega; |g(X_t(\omega))-g(X_s(\omega))| > \epsilon\} \subseteq \{\omega; |X_t(\omega)-X_s(\omega)| >\delta\}.$

Comment: @WalterWhite Let $\omega$ such that $|g(X_t(\omega))-g(X_s(\omega))|>\epsilon$, we have $|X_t(\omega)-X_s(\omega)|>\delta$ ... and that's it. (Note that, by the uniform continuity, we have $|g(X_t(\omega))-g(X_s(\omega))| \leq \epsilon$ if $|X_t(\omega)-X_s(\omega)| \leq \delta$. So if the difference is larger than $\epsilon$, we have, necessarily, $|X_t(\omega)-X_s(\omega)|>\delta$.)